# BIOS won't recognize second hard disk without restarting

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-10, ssd, bios

I just bought a new SSD and placed it in my laptop (Dell Inspiron 3521). I also bought a CD-hard disk caddy, so I placed the old hard disk instead of the CD case.

I installed Windows 10 and fedora, partitioning the two drives as instructed by many guides. I thought it was a problem of Linux as I couldn't boot to them every time, without restart. After so many days of searching, I figured that BIOS caused the problem.

It won't recognize my hard disk (and I am sure not a bootable USB neither) every time. I need to restart the system and everything works fine. If I restart once more, hard disk isn't there, etc..

This problem is so weird, and I can't figure out what can it be..Changing BIOS options didn't help..

Any hints?

Comment: Did you ever have problems accessing the DVD drive?

Comment: @Jonno No, as far as I remember, there was never a problem, I used to burn some DVDs sometimes..

Comment: And you believe it can't see bootable USB devices at the same time? I was suspicious there may be a problem with the caddy - it may be worth just removing and reseating the hard drive. Although if it can't see USB devices also this is unlikely to be related. Have you installed the [latest BIOS](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=3T28M&fileId=3481897272&osCode=WT64A&productCode=inspiron-15-3521&languageCode=EN&categoryId=BI) for your machine?

Comment: Yes, latest update is on..Just made a test with another USB, restarted 6-7 times and it was always there. So i guess the problem is with the candy..It was the only thing I wished for, i should test again with a new one and see the results. Thank you very much....

Comment: It may be worth just removing the caddy from the machine, removing the drive from the caddy and re-seating everything. I am assuming you never had any problems with the hard drive before either?

Comment: what brand of cd hard disk caddy?

Comment: @Moab it is bought from ebay, i think no brand...

Comment: They can be hit and miss on quality. Try a different one.